# Mobile width horizontal and vertical are the same (RWD)

Tags: android, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a responsive website. Unfortunatelly I've noticed some issue. Here is a part of my CSS:

```
header h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
    header h1 {
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        font-size: 3em;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I open this website on my mobile phone in Chrome (Android 4.3) it enables the second option (media query), no matter phone is placed horizontal or vertical. I have Samssung Galaxy SIII LTE (GT-I9305) which has 720 x 1280 px (4.80") 306ppi screen.

So I ran this jQuery code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    alert( $(window).width() );
}
```

And it showed me '960px' in both horizontal and vertical view! Even this meta tag doesn't help.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

So... my question is how to force browser to adopt full dimensions of device?

//EDIT

I tried also 'max-device-width' (no results) and

```
@media all and (orientation: portrait) {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

The portrait option worked fine, but not completely, cause when I tap on some input or textarea (in vertical view), the phone is showing a keyboard which causes switching back to landscape view :(

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like everything is working as it should.

You have a set of styles to be applied at max-width of 1000px, and your phone is 960px (which is less than 1000).

Basically anything 1000px and below will trigger that text-align:center, display:block, font-size: 3em.

Have you established what exact width you want your RWD to be applied? Maybe try lowering max-width to 959px?

Comment: Right, my mistake. But the problem is that javascript is reading width of device as 960px in landscape orientation and also 960px in portrait orientation... but  my screen is not square LOL. And it looks that media query is doing the same, because max-width 959px doesn't solve my problem.

I've tested it on Mozilla and Native Android browser and theirs behaviour is the same.

Comment: Yeah that is strange. Media queries always take me a few tries before getting the exact formula correct. Check out this post, it has a lot of handy queries with their relative devices: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: I solved my problem :) I used <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0"> and then width of device for media query is 360px (vertical) and 640px (horizontal) so everything is ok.